# How do I declare a Dictionary in VB.Net with a string key and a named Tuple as the value?

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, tuples

I'm declaring a data structure and loading it up with data

```
    Public Shared LexerEnglishFullWithTuple As New Dictionary(Of String, Object) From {
{"LET", (1, "000000001", 0)},
{"PUT", (2, "000000002", 2)},
...
```

What I'd like to be able to do is name the components of the ValueTuple and to a certain extent this works, viz,

```
    Public Shared LexerEnglishFullWithTuple As New Dictionary(Of String, Object) From {
{"LET", (Id:=1, IdString:="000000001", Arity:=0)},
{"PUT", (Id:=2, IdString:="000000002", Arity:=2)},
...
```

What I'm stuck on at the moment is the `As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)` where it would be nice to be able to put something other than Object. I've tried things like `Tuple`, `ValueTuple` and various of those with `(Of` but nothing seems to compile.

In my tests, because it's just `Of String,Object` I can't see Id, IdString and Arity, I can only see Item1, Item2 and Item3

```
        <Fact>
        Sub TestSub2()
            Dim FEL = Lexers.English.LexerEnglishFullWithTuple
            Dim x = FEL("EDS")
            Dim y = From el In FEL Where el.Value.Item1 = 861220001 Select el.Key
            Assert.Equal("EDS", y(0))
        End Sub
```

Comment: I've filed a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/24823) on the VB.NET [tuple documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/tuples).

Comment: In order to do a clear and future-maintainable work I think you have to use a `Structure` than `ValueTuple`. Then you can declare a Dictionary(Of String, YourStructure). After that you have not issues of late binding as named types under a LINQ query are inherited as well.

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj Where don't the tuple names propagate? This compiles: `LexerEnglishFullWithTuple.Values.Select(Function(x) $"{x.Id}, {x.IdString}, {x.Arity}")`.

Comment: @ZevSpitz Yes, No doubts. But was approach related my comment. In my case I’m going never to declare a dictionary with an inline `ValueTuple`. A `Structure` it’s seen by me as more compact and better approach for named types as alternative of `ValueTuple`.
Said that. It's only my “modus operandi” and I think is not a bad advice considering `ValueTuple` are limited to a certain upper version of .NET and importing some Nuget Package.

Comment: And more important: My comment was refereed to OP code not your code, where the dictionary was Of Object

Comment: The documentation [has been updated](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/main/docs/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/tuples.md#instantiating-and-using-a-named-tuple); and can be seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/tuples#instantiating-and-using-a-named-tuple).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Dim LexerEnglishFullWithTuple As New Dictionary(Of String, (Id As Integer, IdString As String, Arity As Integer)) From {
    {"LET", (1, "000000001", 0)},
    {"PUT", (2, "000000002", 2)}
}

For Each x In LexerEnglishFullWithTuple
    Dim value = x.Value
    Console.WriteLine(value.Id)
    Console.WriteLine(value.IdString)
    Console.WriteLine(value.Arity)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You just declare the name and type of the tuple's properties like you would any other:

```vb
Public Shared LexerEnglishFullWithTuple As New Dictionary(Of String, (Id As Integer, IdString As String, Arity As Integer)) From {
    {"LET", (1, "000000001", 0)},
    {"PUT", (2, "000000002", 2)},
    '...
```